# Save large text file without using too much memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I have a model that creates a KML file. I treat that KML as a string and then forward that to mailer which then delivers it:

```
def write_kml(coords3d, time)
  kml = String.new
    kml << header
    coords3d.each do |coords|
      coordinates = String.new
      coords.each do |coord|
        lat = coord[0].to_f
        lng = coord[1].to_f
        coordinates << "#{lng}" + "," "#{lat}" + ",0 "
        kml <<  polygon(coordinates)
      end
      end

    kml <<  footer
  kml

end
```

This gets used here:

```
  CsvMailer.kml_send(kml,time, mode, email).deliver
```

Mailer:

```
  def kml_send(kml, time, mode, email)
    @time = (time / 60).to_i
    @mode = mode
    gen_time = Time.now
    file_name = gen_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + " #{@mode.to_s}" + " #{@time.to_s}(mins)"
    attachments[file_name + '(KML).kml'] = { mime_type: 'text/kml', content: kml}
    mail to: email, subject: ' KML Filem'
  end
```

It takes up a huge amount of memory. Some of these files are quite large (200MB), so on Heroku for example, they take up too much space.

I had some ideas using S3, but I would need to create this file to begin with, so it would still use the memory. Can I write straight to S3 without using memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with s3 multipart uploads, since they don't require you to know the file size upfront.

Parts have to be at least 5MB in size, so the easiest way to use this is to write your data to an in memory buffer and upload the part to s3 every time you get past 5MB. There's a limit of 10000 parts for an upload, so if your file size is going to be > 50GB then you'd need to know that ahead of time so that you can make the parts bigger.

Using the fog library, that would look a little like

```
def upload_chunk connection, upload_id, chunk, index
    md5 = Base64.encode64(Digest::MD5.digest(chunk)).strip
    connection.upload_part('bucket', 'a_key', upload_id, chunk_index, chunk, 'Content-MD5' => md5 )
end


connection = Fog::Storage::AWS.new(:aws_access_key_id => '...', :region => '...', :aws_secret_access_key => '...'
upload_id = connection.initiate_multipart_upload('bucket', 'a_key').body['UploadId']
chunk_index = 1

kml = String.new
kml << header
coords3d.each do |coords|
  #append to kml
  if kml.bytesize > 5 * 1024 * 1024
    upload_chunk connection, upload_id, kml, chunk_index
    chunk_index += 1
    kml = ''
  end
end
upload_chunk connection, upload_id, kml, chunk_index
#when you've uploaded all the chunks
connection.complete_multipart_upload('bucket', 'a_key', upload_id)
```

You could probably come up with something neater if you created an uploader class to wrap the buffer and stuck all the s3 logic in there. Then your kml code doesn't have to know whether it has an actual string or a string that flushes to s3 periodically

Comment: thanks, how would I know which part has hit 5 Meg? and does it join them all together the other end?

Comment: As you append to your string you just need to check every so often whether it is over 5MB. if it is, upload the chunk (doesn't have to be exactly 5MB). S3 takes care of all the joining

Comment: would you mind including an example? I am struggling to split it reliably every 5meg or so

Comment: I've spelled it out a bit more

Comment: hero, it was very close to what I had, however the bytesize method works much better! thanks!